# Простая реализация функции для разбора параметров командной строки (getopt)

Tags: python, командная-строка

Хочу устроиться на работу, и один из вопросов:

**Напишите простую реализацию функции для разбора параметров командной строки (*getopt*).**

Полагаем, что нам требуется структура данных, содержащая заранее известный допустимый набор параметров различного типа - `строки`, `целые числа`, `числа с плавающей точкой` и т. д., а также `признак, является ли этот параметр обязательным`.

Полагаем, что параметры могут передаваться только в "длинном" формате с обязательным `--` перед именем параметра (*то есть `--my-option-name my-option-val`, `--my-option-name=my-option-val`, `--my-boolean-option`*).

Параметров может быть несколько.

Функция должна обязательно уметь обрабатывать параметр `--help` (*если он указан в списке параметров при вызове функции*), выводящий пример использования (*необязательные параметры должны выводиться в квадратных скобках*).

Подскажите, что от меня хотят, я не понимаю задание...

Написать надо на `python`.

Comment: почитайте о модуле `argparse` - от вас хотят, чтобы вы написали упрощенный вариант этого модуля...

Comment: Спасибо, стало понятнее, но все равно не до конца. Мне нужно написать функцию, в которую нельзя добавить параметр, а только использовать готовые написанные в ней?(аля --сложи(3)и(5)) и параметр help который выводит эти параметры и описание?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно создать парсер аргументов, который будет работать с массивом `sys.argv`.

Грубо говоря, вам нужно создать класс, который будет способен на следующее:

Работать с длинными аргументами (например, `--help` или `--value=2`)

Который при запуске скрипта с аргументом `--help` будет выводить помощь к скрипту, где **необязательные аргументы** будут указаны **в квадратных скобках**.

Парсер должен быть способен обрабатывать множество аргументов.

[Документация](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/getopt.html) по `getopt`
[Документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) по `argparse`

Comment: спасибо, теперь все понял

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы реализовать аналог [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse), [docopt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docopt), достаточно указать способ как задать ожидаемые параметры командной строки и распознать действительные аргументы, переданные программе, которые этим параметрам соответствуют.

Для спецификации параметров можно использовать аннотацию функции `main()`, которая вызывается при старте скрипта:

```
REQUIRED = object()

@simple_cli(__doc__)
def main(*, number: int = REQUIRED, flag: bool = False):
    # some filler code that uses the parsed args
    print(number + 1, flag, sep=' | ')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Это говорит, что скрипт принимает два параметра `--number` и `--flag`. `--number` принимает целое значение и является обязательным, а `--flag` это простой булевый флаг (очевидно, что необязательный и выключенный по умолчанию).

Здесь `simple_cli()` это декоратор, который превращает `sys.argv` (аргументы командной строки) в фактические параметры функции `main()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: parse-args --number=<int> [--flag]"""    
import inspect
import functools
import sys

def simple_cli(description):
    """Implement a simple annotation-based command-line parser."""
    def decorator(main):
        @functools.wraps(main)
        def wrapper(argv=None):
            if argv is None:
                argv = sys.argv
            if '--help' in argv:
                sys.exit(description)
            params = inspect.signature(main).parameters
            parser = ArgumentParser.from_params(*params.values())
            try:
                return main(**parser.parse_args(argv[1:]))
            except ArgumentError as e:
                sys.exit(f"Error: {e}\n{description}")
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Примеры использования:

```
$ parse-args.py --help
Usage: parse-args --number=<int> [--flag]
$ parse-args --number=1 --flag
2 | True
```

Здесь в качестве `--help` сообщения выступает docstring модуля. При желании, можно сгенерировать `usage` автоматически из объявления `main()`  функции, чтобы устранить дублирование информации о параметрах. Или наоборот: из docstring сгенерировать парсер для аргументов командной строки как это [docopt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docopt) делает.

Фактическим распознаванием аргументов занимается класс `ArgumentParser`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Parameter = namedtuple('Parameter', 'name type required')

class ArgumentError(Exception):
    pass

class ArgumentParser:
    """(--option[=value])*"""

    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = params  # parameters specification

    @classmethod
    def from_params(cls, *params):
        return cls({p.name: Parameter(p.name,
                                      str if p.annotation is p.empty else p.annotation,
                                      p.default is REQUIRED)
                    for p in params if p.kind == p.KEYWORD_ONLY})

    def parse_args(self, argv):
        args = {name[2:]: value if '=' in arg else None
                for arg in argv for name, value in [arg.partition('=')[::2]]}
        required_params = {
            p.name: p for p in self.params.values() if p.required}
        if not (required_params.keys() <= args.keys()):
            raise ArgumentError("missing required parameters")
        if not (args.keys() <= self.params.keys()):
            raise ArgumentError("unknown parameters")

        for name, value in args.items():
            param = self.params[name]
            if param.type is bool:
                if value is not None:
                    raise ArgumentError("flag with a value")
                args[name] = True
            elif param.type is not str:
                if value is None:
                    raise ArgumentError(f"--{name} option is missing value")
                try:
                    args[name] = param.type(value)
                except ValueError as e:
                    raise ArgumentError(str(e))

        return args
```

С точки зрения `Argparser` каждый аргумент имеет вид `--option[=value]`, где квадратные скобки говорят, что значение может не присутствовать. `--option value` не поддерживается (можно добавить).

Спецификация возможных параметров представлена списком `Parameter` объектов. `from_params()` конвертирует спецификацию из `inspect.Parameter`  формата в `Parameter(name, type, required)`.

`parse_args()` превращает аргументы командной строки (`sys.argv[1:]`) в аргументы, которые можно в `main()` передать. Код прямолинейный. Заметная часть посвящена выбрасыванию `ArgumentError` исключения, если входные аргументы не соответствуют заданной спецификации.